# Is it possible to format each value using supplied format?

Tags: c#, .net, dotliquid

I have this program

```
private static void RunUsingILiquidizable()
{
    const string templateString = @"TopInt prop: '{{TopInt}}'; Child.Prop prop: '{{L1Prop.L1Int}}'; Child.Child.Prop prop: '{{L1Prop.L2Prop.L2Int}}'; Dict item: '{{ExtendedProps.Key1}}'";
    Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();
    Template.RegisterValueTypeTransformer(typeof(DateTime), (v) => ((DateTime)v).ToString("MM=dd=yy"));
    var t = Template.Parse(templateString);

    var model = new TopModel()
    {
        TopInt = 23,
        L1Prop = new L1Model()
        {
            L1Int = 34,
            L2Prop = new L2Model() { L2Int = 98 }
        },
        ExtendedProps = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Key1", DateTime.Now } }
    };

    string output = t.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(model));

    Console.WriteLine("RunUsingILiquidizable -->" + output);

}
```

Top Model definition:

```
public class TopModel : ILiquidizable
{
    public int TopInt { get; set; }
    public L1Model L1Prop { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtendedProps { get; set; }
    public object ToLiquid()
    {
        return new { TopInt, L1Prop, ExtendedProps };
    }
}
```

Output:

> RunUsingILiquidizable -->TopInt prop: '23'; Child.Prop prop: '34'; Child.Child.P
>   rop prop: '98'; Dict item: '08=27=19'

My problem is - `Template.RegisterValueTypeTransformer` does global type format and `template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(model), MyFormatProvider)` formats all dates, numbers the same.

What I need is to format each specific token differently when needed by supplying format. Especially important for dictionary `ExtendedProps`.

I tried to do filters as well but is there a way to pass something like `{{ExtendedProps.Key1 | SpecialFormat("dd--MM")}}` ??

Comment: It doesn't look like you can parameterize a filter but you might try creating a filter for each format you want to support.

Comment: @madreflection yes, I would be able to create a filter class for each class if I knew what it would be. Lets say I need `currency` for French culture. Next model I might need to format value as currency for US culture. Hmm, I need to think. I might need to set the culture on the thread and currency as filter. We might have the winner!

Comment: That's what came to my mind, too, as I read the words "French culture". If it's just culture-specific formatting, I think you're on to something.

Comment: @madreflection I need to work on specs. As of right now, specific format is set for each field. Well, this is open source, I might have to take ownership or propose new functionality. Don't know right now.

Comment: @madreflection My problem has changed the shape a bit, but still remains. Yes, I forced change of requirement, we can process all variables according to same culture, however, they need to be in different format. I can create filters right?. But filters don't account for culture set in `template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(model), MyFormatProvider)`. For example, built-in `currency` filter can work like this `{{a.b|currency:"fr-Fr"}}` but no way I can add hard-coded culture in template text. Yea, I can set culture on threasd itself but in multi-threaded environment it can backfire

Comment: I've never used DotLiquid before but I started playing with it and I think you're in luck. Take a look at my answer. Also, the counter to setting the culture on the thread is passing a `CultureInfo` as the `formatProvider` parameter to the `Render` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to examine the source code for the `StandardFilters` class.  Custom filters can do more than the wiki docs would have you believe, and the standard filters demonstrate much of it.  If there's something you've seen the standard filters do, you can write a custom filter that does the same thing.

Here's an example `custom_date` filter:

```cs
public static class CustomFilter
{
    public static string CustomDate(Context context, object input, string format = null, string culture = null)
    {
        if (input is DateTime dt)
        {
            IFormatProvider formatProvider = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture)
                ? CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture)
                : context.FormatProvider;

            return dt.ToString(format, formatProvider);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Points of interest:

1. It accepts an initial `Context` parameter, which includes a `FormatProvider` property of type `IFormatProvider` (which `CultureInfo` implements).  You only need to include this parameter if you need something from it.
2. It accepts multiple parameters:

   a. A format, like certain `ToString` overloads, and just passes it through.

   b. A locale for which it retrieves the `CultureInfo` or, if `null` or `""`, defaults to  `context.FormatProvider`, which is either the optional `IFormatProvider` passed to `Render` or the current culture.
3. The parameters are defaulted.  This is probably a good idea in general because there's no way to make them required in the template.

**Example usage**

```cs
Template.Register(typeof(CustomFilter));

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
var template = Template.Parse("Today is {{ today | custom_date: 'd' }} (current culture), {{ today | custom_date: 'd', 'fr-CA' }} (fr-CA), and {{ today | custom_date: 'd', elsewhere }} ({{ elsewhere }}).");
string output = template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { today = DateTime.Today, elsewhere = "de-DE" }));
```

**Output**

> Today is 8/30/2019 (current culture), 2019-08-30 (fr-CA), and 30.08.2019 (de-DE).

More points of interest:

1. The parameters are specified after a colon and separated by a comma if there's more than one.
2. Values in the "hash" that you pass to `Render` can be referenced in the parameters you pass (e.g. `elsewhere`).
3. The `"d"` standard format is sensitive to the culture so you can see how the current culture (`en-US`), a hard-coded culture (`fr-CA`), and a parameterized culture (`de-DE`) can all be used.

Comment: BINGO! Thank you for comprehensive answer. This is what I was looking for `FilterDaysFromNow(Context ctx, object input)`. Because context has `IFormatProvider` passed during `Render`. What a relieve! I downloaded the code and I do some of my unit tests related to multi-threading error suppression and custom filters. I went into wrong direction. I thought how to implement custom filter using instance class that implements `IContextAware`, I also tried filter like this `Filter(object input, IFormatProvider f)`. You just took me **right there** and I appreciate it truly.

Comment: Hey, that's fantastic! I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: *"2. It accepts multiple parameters:"* - this is the thing - I don't want parameters. We're building editor for this. People will have choice of standard properties from object signature and dynamic properties from dictionary. On top of that, people will pick a data type for the dynamic property and format. Only they will not type-in the format but rather pick from the list of Date/Time filters. For example `Format_LongDate, Format_ShortDate, Format_Time`.  The original request will come with culture they want, otherwise standard US culture will be used. I could set the culture on thread...

Comment: ... but I think it is better to isolate it during `ToString`. So the code will look like `.ToString("G", context.FormatProvider)` Job done!